# How to show Audit logs as linear table? and what is the best representation for the logs table in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi

I have a table Main, where all action are taking place, every action would require change status or change of stage, below some example data

Main table

| ID | Status | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

Status Table

| ID | Status Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Waiting Customer |
| 2 | Approve |
| 3 | Rejected |
| 4 | Pending |
| 5 | Other |

Stage Table

| ID | Stage Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage 1 |
| 2 | Stage 2 |
| 3 | Stage 3 |

Audit and SLA table

| Start Date Time | End Date Time | SLA Breached | Status | Stage | Main ID | User Name | Record Date Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/10/2023 12:37 PM | 7/11/2023 12:37 PM | Yes | 1 | 1 | 1 | User A | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/12/2023 12:37 PM | 7/13/2023 12:37 PM | No | 2 | 1 | 1 | User B | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/13/2023 12:37 PM | 7/14/2023 12:37 PM | No | 3 | 1 | 1 | User C | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/14/2023 12:37 PM | 7/15/2023 12:37 PM | No | 1 | 2 | 1 | User D | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/14/2023 12:37 PM | 7/16/2023 12:37 PM | No | 2 | 2 | 1 | User B | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/16/2023 12:37 PM | 7/17/2023 12:37 PM | No | 3 | 1 | 1 | User D | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/17/2023 12:37 PM | 7/18/2023 12:37 PM | Yes | 1 | 2 | 1 | User C | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |
| 7/18/2023 12:37 PM | 7/19/2023 12:37 PM | No | 1 | 3 | 1 | User B | 7/26/2023 12:37 PM |

Now i need to export the audit logs to excel sheet as a readable linear report

| Main ID | Stage 1 | Status | Start | End | SLA Breached | Stage 2 | Status | Start | End | SLA Breached |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. | ……. |

what is the best representation of this logs in excel

I know that in pivot table the columns must be static but in my case the columns are dynamic.